# "Distance" between distributions and convergence of Markov chains

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains, entropy

For what follows, let us restrict ourselves to discussing *discrete* probability distributions.

When learning about things like relative entropy (aka Kullback-Leibler divergence) $D(\cdot || \cdot)$, one typically learns that it does not technically define a metric, since $D(P||Q) \ne D(Q||P)$, for some distributions $P,Q$.

In general, I don't think there is any well-defined notion of distance between two probability distributions.

However, when learning about Markov chains, we learn about nice conditions under which some distribution $\pi_0$ converges to the stationary distribution of the Markov chain $\pi$ (assuming it exists).

Since there is no well-defined metric on the set of probability distributions, what is going on here? How is this convergence defined? In precisely what sense is $\pi_0$ approaching $\pi$? Is there some (obvious) underlying topology that I am just not seeing? Can someone help reconcile what's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many possible topologies on the space of all probability distributions.  You can see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures for an overview.  The most commonly encountered is the *weak topology*; one of several equivalent definitions is that a sequence of probability measures $P_n$ on, say, $\mathbb{R}$, converges to $P$ iff $\int f\,dP_n \to \int f\,dP$ for every bounded continuous function $f$.  It's also called "convergence in law" or "convergence in distribution".  It is discussed in most graduate-level probability books (e.g. Durrett, Resnick).  The canonical source to learn more is Billingsley, *Convergence of Probability Measures.*

It is true, for instance, that under appropriate conditions, the $n$-step distribution of a Markov chain converges, in the weak topology, to the stationary distribution.

> In general, I don't think there is any well-defined notion of distance between two probability distributions.

Well, you are incorrect.    The K-L divergence doesn't happen to be a metric, but there are plenty of other metrics.  For instance, there's the [Lévy metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_metric), which induces the weak topology.  The total variation distance is also a metric, but it induces a different (and less useful) topology.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Just to confirm, things don't become significantly simpler if we only look at discrete distributions?

Comment: @theQman I just wanted to point out the square root of the Jensen-Shannon divergence (a symmetric and smoothed version of KL divergence) is a metric.